# Connecting VB6 and MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to create a simple visual basic 6 program/database that uses ms access 2007 as the back end. I have no background with vb programming. I just want to as what are the simplest way(s) in connecting vb and access? I've searched almost all over the internet on how to do this but I think I'm doing it wrong. Can anybody help me?  Thanks.

Comment: If you know nothing about VB6, there's no reason to start using it at this point.  The Visual Basic 6 IDE was end-of-lifed [back in 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708).  Microsoft offers [modern versions of Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) at no cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ADO. Theres a tutorial in the VB6 user guide about connecting VB6 to Access. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240855(v=vs.60).aspx

You will need to use an appropriate connection string for Access 2007. http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007

Answer (score 2):

These websites might be suitable for you. I found them using Google and searching for "vb 6 access 2007".



A suggestion from http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/visual-basic-4-5-6/threads/110825 is:

Don't use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 for provider. You need to use the
"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

The easiest way is to setup a Data Link or a Data Provider.

A suggestion from http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=472469 is:

If you were using the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library, try removing the reference to it and instead, set a reference to Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object Library.

The best answer from http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090209051024AAl8ZRC is:

```
Const DBNAME = "c:\customer.mdb"    

Set objFSOA = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject…    
If not objFSOA.FileExists(DBNAME) Then        
    CreateDatabase    
End if    

Set objConnectionA = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")    
objConnectionA.Open "Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & "Data Source= " & DBNAME    
Dim strSQL     
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Test(col_1, col_2) VALUES (23, 'Test');"     

objConnectionA.Execute(strSQL)     

objConnectionA.Close    

Private Sub CreateDatabase()    
    Dim objADOXDatabase    
    Set objADOXDatabase = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")    
    objADOXDatabase.Create "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & DBNAME    
    Set objConnectionA = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")    
    objConnectionA.Open "Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & "Data Source= " & DBNAME    
    objConnectionA.Execute "Create Table Test(col_1 number, col_2 text(10))"    
    objConnectionA.Close    

 End Sub
```

The suggested answer from http://www.database-answers.com/microsoft/Access-Modules-DAO/32414159/opening-access-2007-in-vb6-accessdatabaseengineexe-acedaodll.aspx is:

```
3) In VB6 Project|References,    
    a) Deselect Microsoft DAO 3.6 object library    
    b) Select Microsoft Office 12 access database engine object library    
    c) Select Microsoft Office 12 object library    
    4) no special code changes needed when setting db objects
```

I hope these suggestions and the links provided will give you some more insight into the relationship between VB 6 and Access 2007.

Comment: My apologies for not providing clearer information to assist the user asking the question. In my own defense I would like to point out that the user asking the question said they could not find any information on the internet to support their request and I was pointing out that a quick search on google resulted in the links above. But as you mentioned this was not a useful answer.