# VB6 & Access 2007 connection problems

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2007, database-connection

OK, so I've read this identical question, but the answers don't work for me:

[Connecting VB6 and MS Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050040/connecting-vb6-and-ms-access-2007)

I've removed the reference to *Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library*, and replaced it with a reference to *Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object*.

Here's my code:

```
Dim rcdSetData As ADODB.Recordset

Set rcdSetData = New ADODB.Recordset
rcdSetData.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rcdSetData.ActiveConnection = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " _
    & "Data Source=" & DBName & "; "
```

I can open Access 2003 *.mdb files just fine, but when I try to open an Access 2007 *.accdb file, I get:

```
Error #blahblah, Unrecognized database format 'C:\path\foo.accdb'
```

foo.accdb is a valid Access 2007 file, as far as Access 2007 cares. No password, BTW, and it isn't open in Access when I run the program.

I'm stumped. EVERY answer I can find on the web says I'm doing this right.... :\

Comment: You need a different connection string for ACCDB.  The Jet provider can only connect to MDB format db files.  You need the ACE provider for ACCDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have recently re-installed VB6, make sure you download and install the service pack SP6 for it.

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

The DAO reference (be it to the pre- or post-Access 2007 version of that library) is irrelevant, since your VB code is using ADO instead. Your problem lies rather with the connection string. Try replacing

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " _
```

with

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " _
```

Comment: I realize DAO is irrelevent; I'm just pointing out what I'm using now instead - and that it works on older databases.

I already tried the ACD engine reference; it has no effect on the problem.

Comment: @JoeMarfice - by 'DAO' I meant both, hence the bracketed bit ('be it to the pre- or post-Access 2007 version of that library'). The so-called 'Access Database Engine Object Library' will always be DAO to me ;-)

Comment: Ah, much clearer when you say what you mean! (And of course, I typoed "ACD engine" when I meant "ACE engine".)

We're having some luck, and not sure why it seems to work in some places but not others... but now when we open the DB, we're finding that we need to update our connections references.

Always something...